# How to pass dev_appserver parameters for django-nonrel

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I have been using django-appengine and am now trying a project with django-nonrel.  Before I used a bash script to start the local server and pass parameters.

[Django-nonrel docs](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#management-commands) say you shouldn't run dev_appserver directly.  Is there a way to pass these parameters?

```
/usr/bin/python2.5 ./dev_appserver.py \
        -p 9009 \
        -a 192.168.1.8 \
        --blobstore_path=/foo/gaedata/myapp/blobs \
        --datastore_path=/foo/gaedata/myapp/data \
        --enable_sendmail \
        $@ .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- IP address and port may be passed as the the first argument (as Robert answered)
- --enable_sendmail works as-is
- The datastore parameters must be separated by a space instead of an equals

Working version:

```
/usr/bin/python2.5 ./manage.py runserver \
        192.168.1.8:9009 \
        --enable_sendmail \
        --blobstore_path /foo/django-nonrel/blobs \
        --datastore_path /foo/data \
        --history_path /foo/history
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you pass the address and port in as the first arguments "192.168.1.8:9009" to your runserver command.

And/or, edit [`/management/commands/runserver.py`](http://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine/src/920e92ddbcd3/management/commands/runserver.py) and add additional parameters.  I think you might be able to set the datastore and blobstore paths in your django db  settings.

Also, I found one [post](http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational/msg/88d0a185b58ec7bd) from Waldemar commenting on this general topic.